# use regex to replace long string

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the string

```
ID12345678_S3_MPRAGE_ADNI_32Ch_2_98_clone_transform_clone_reg_N3Corrected1_mask_cp_strip_durastripped_N3Corrected_clone_lToads_lesions_seg
```

with

```
ID12345678
```

How can I replace this via regex?

I tried this - it didn't work.

```
import re
re.sub(r'_\w+_\d_\d+_\w+','')
```

Thank you

Comment: `re.sub(r'_\w+_\d_\d+_\w+','')` won't do anything at all -- you need 3 arguments -- and if you want `re.match`, the second argument should be your long input string, not an empty string.  Also, if `s` is your long input string, a naive solution would be simply `s[0:10]` or `s[0:s.find('_')]`.

Comment: if you just want the number and its the beginning of every string just use find like @jedwards showed

Comment: I think you actually want `re.match` (if the string is guaranteed to be at the start of the input) or `re.search` otherwise, not `re.sub` -- provided, at least, you're not trying to do in-line replacement in a much longer string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with pattern `[^_]*` that match any sub-string from your text that not contain `_` and as `re.sub` replace the pattern for first match you can use it in this case :

```
>>> s="ID12345678_S3_MPRAGE_ADNI_32Ch_2_98_clone_transform_clone_reg_N3Corrected1_mask_cp_strip_durastripped_N3Corrected_clone_lToads_lesions_seg"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([^_]*).*',r'\1',s)
'ID12345678'
```

But if it could be appear any where in your string you can use `re.search` as following :

```
>>> re.search(r'ID\d+',s).group(0)
'ID12345678'
>>> s="_S3_MPRAGE_ADNI_ID12345678_32Ch_2_98_clone_transform_clone_reg_N3Corrected1_mask_cp_strip_durastripped_N3Corrected_clone_lToads_lesions_seg"
>>> re.search(r'ID\d+',s).group(0)
'ID12345678'
```

But without regex simply you can use `split()` :

```
>>> s.split('_',1)[0]
'ID12345678'
```

Comment: Thank you - the first option works very. But since my very long ID is in a pandas-dataframe read from a csv-file it doesn't work. Do I have to add something in this case such as \b for the boundary?

Comment: One more question - the \1 refers to the first capturing group right? So how does it know which characters separates capturing groups? Thank you.

Comment: I found it out - if a regular expression is used in pandas dataframe.replace() regex=True has to be set.

Comment: @Swankyleo glad that hear that! As im not familiar with pandas! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first part is variable, then

```
import re
s = "ID12345678_S3_MPRAGE_ADNI_32Ch_2_98_clone_transform_clone_reg_N3Corrected1_mask_cp_strip_durastripped_N3Corrected_clone_lToads_lesions_seg"
print re.sub(r'_.*$', r'', s)
```